# What does Jenova's head plate say?

Tags: final-fantasy

I can't quite read her inscribed plate, and a Roman or [normal](https://www.deviantart.com/art/Jenova-343773529) date doesn't appear to match.

```
JENOVA
MADE IN ???
ALL RIGHTS RESERVED 1999
POWER COMPANY LIMITED
```

[image: FF7 Steam version Jenova head plate]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[This page](http://www.ff7citadel.com/secrets/s_jenova.shtml) has the answer:

> A higher-resolution version of the FMV featuring Jenova's helmet can
>   be seen in the intro of "Distance", the FFVII:AC "making-of"
>   featurette that's included on both the Japanese "Advent Pieces" bonus
>   disk and the one included with the English-language version. Here is
>   the best screenshot we could take of Jenova's helmet, as it appears in
>   "Distance":
>
> [image: Jenova helmet HD]
>
> ```
> MADE IN HONG KONG
> ALL RIGHTS RESERVED 1996
> SQUER COMPANY LIMITED
> ```